# How to navigate from a Composable to an Activity in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation, android-jetpack-compose

What are the ways in which navigation is possible between a composable and an Activity and vice versa?
Can I do it by using the `startActivity(...)` method or is the only way to create Screens and NavController?

[image: Android Studio Screenshot]

Comment: To have a composable start an activity, you can use `ContextAmbient` to get a `Context`. You might be able to use Navigation for Compose to create a nav graph that uses both [`activity()`](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-kotlin-dsl#activity) and [`composable()`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#create-navhost) destinations, though I have not tried that yet.

Comment: Using 'ContextAmbient.current' gives Intent but Context is needed. Can you please show that in an example?

Comment: No, [`ContextAmbient` provides a `Context`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/platform/package-summary#ContextAmbient:androidx.compose.runtime.ProvidableAmbient). Though it appears to be being renamed to `AmbientContext`, based on [the source code](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:compose/ui/ui/src/androidMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/platform/AndroidAmbients.kt;l=63-79?q=ContextAmbient&ss=androidx).

Comment: @CommonsWare, please refer to the image

Comment: I do not know what `startActivity()` function you are trying to call. The error is showing that you are passing an `Intent` to it, and it is expecting a `Context` (at least as the first parameter). Your `Intent` is coming from the `Intent()` constructor that you are calling. I was expecting you to do `val context = ContextAmbient.current; context.startActivity(Intent(context, ListActivity::class.java))` (semicolon used here just because Stack Overflow comments can't handle newlines).

Answer (score 91, accepted):

In newer version of compose use `LocalContext`.
In older versions (*1.0.0-alpha08* and before) use `AmbientContext`:

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
    val context = LocalContext.current

    Button(onClick = {
        context.startActivity(Intent(context, ListActivity::class.java))
    }) {
        Text(text = "Show List")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's how I usually do it (and pass values to another activity):

```
val context = LocalContext.current
...
onClick = {
    val intent = Intent(context, ListActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra(YourExtraKey, YourExtraValue)
    context.startActivity(intent)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `LocalContext.current` to navigate to another Activity from a `Composable` you can pass the `onClick` callback to `Activity`/`Fragment` and navigate like before. Here is an example:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            AndroidTheme {
                Surface(...) {
                    Greeting (onClick = {
                        // this here is MainActivity
                        startDetailActivity()
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun startDetailActivity() {
        val intent = Intent(this, DetailActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(onClick: () -> Unit) {
    
    Button(onClick = onClick) {
        Text(text = "Button")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

startNewActivity is a function pass context , any class and Bundle it can be null ,

.clickable { startNewActivity(context,DetailsActivity::class.java) },

```
   fun  startNewActivity(context: Context,activityClass: Class<*>, bundle: Bundle? = null){
                val intent = Intent(context, activityClass)
            bundle.let {    intent.putExtras(bundle!!) }
                context.startActivity(intent)
            }
```