# How to navigate from second activity to a compos with an argument in Jetpack compose?

Tags: android-activity, parameter-passing, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I implemented Rewarded Interstitial Ad in my jetpack project. I used the second activity to show the ad and now I want to implement OnUserEarnedRewardListener. My user can see the last screen after the ad finishes. I find it challenging to navigate from compos to activity and conversely with an argument. These are my Screen and NavGraph.

```
sealed class Screens (val route: String){
    object SMasks: Screens("s_masks")
    object BMasks: Screens("b_masks")
    object FinalShow: Screens("final_show")
    object ProgressBar: Screens("progress_bar")
    object RewardedShow: Screens("rewarded_show")

}
```

and this is my NavGraph

```
@SuppressLint("UnrememberedMutableState")
@Composable
fun MyNavGraph(

navController: NavHostController

) {
    val actions = remember(navController) { MainActions(navController) }

NavHost(
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = BottomNavItems.SMasks.route
) {
    composable(BottomNavItems.SMasks.route) {
        SMaskScreen(actions
        )
    }

    composable(
        Screens.BMasks.route
    ) {

        BMasksScreen(navController, actions)
    }
   
    composable("${Screens.FinalShow.route}/{maskArg}") {
        val maskArg = it.arguments?.getString("maskArg")
        if (maskArg != null) {
            FinalShowScreen(
                maskArg = maskArg, navController
            )
        }
     }

   }

 }

} 

class MainActions(navController: NavController) {

val gotoFinalShow: (String) -> Unit = { maskArg ->
    navController.navigate("${Screens.FinalShow.route}/$maskArg") {
        launchSingleTop = true
        restoreState = true
    }
}
```

this is my code that when the user clicks on it navigate to RewardShowActivity.

```
 onItemClick =  {
                    maskArg = "mask1"
                    goToActivity(maskArg = maskArg, context = context)
                }

fun goToActivity(context: Context, maskArg: String) {
val intent = Intent(context, RewardedShowActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("maskArg", maskArg)
context.startActivity(intent)
}
```

and this is my RewardedShowActivity

```
class RewardedShowActivity : ComponentActivity(), OnUserEarnedRewardListener {

val loading = mutableStateOf(true)

private companion object{
    const val TAG = "TAG"
}
private var mRewardedInterstitialAd: RewardedInterstitialAd? = null


@SuppressLint("UnrememberedMutableState")
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val maskArg =  intent.extras!!.getString("maskArg")

    setContent {

        MyAppTheme {

            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
            ) {
                CircleIndeterminateProgressBar(isDisplayed = 
loading )

            }
        }
    }

override fun onUserEarnedReward(p0: RewardItem) {
  ??????????
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are ways to navigate from composable to another activity e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65088035/how-to-navigate-from-a-composable-to-an-activity-or-a-fragment-in-jetpack-compos)
But the beauty of Compose is in having all your code within Compose, so if you show your ad as a composable and not a separate activity then you won't have any issues.
Can you rethink your code design so there is only a single Activity? (which is by the way the current google-recommended way)

Comment: Thanks, @David A. Actually, I am trying to implement it in compoe but have faced some errors.  For example

Comment: That's fine, we're all learning Compose, it's somewhat new. Did you create a question with the errors you faced, I can have look.

Comment: thanks, @David d. just implemented it successfully in compose. thanks