# Make search result in lazy column clickable

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have an hymn book app with a search button on button click it opens a search bar page. This page goes through the data class and returns the result of the text if it is found in the list of items in the data class. The search bar produces the required result of the string in a new lazy column but it doesn't go to hymnscreen.

```
val viewModel: SearchViewModel = viewModel()
val songList = viewModel.list.observeAsState().value

LazyColumn {
    if (!songList.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        items(songList) { song ->
            Card(modifier = Modifier
.clickable(onClick ={
HymnActivity:class.java).apply{
                         putExtra("SONG_KEY",song)
})
.fillMaxWidth(),
shape = RoundedShape(10.dp))
{
Text(
                text = song.title,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6,
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.onBackground,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(horizontal = 20.dp, vertical = 12.dp)
                    .wrapContentWidth(Alignment.Start)
            )
        }
}
    }
}
```

I tried making the card in the lazy column clickable

```
context.startActivity(Intent(HymnActivity::class.java))
```

It didn't work. There are multiple Items in the list. And a view model that goes through the items in that list. That should connect to a composable and show a screen title = song.title

lyrics = song.lyrics

Comment: Can you please post some code where you are trying to make the lazy column clickable and it is not working, so that I can advise?

Comment: Have you tried this answer yet? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65190270/13258270

Comment: I have the app keeps restarting on click of the card.